# The Hausdorff dimension of the set of solutions of a system of  coupled differential equations

Tags: dynamical-systems, fractals

I am interested in the relationship between non-linear differential equations and the Hausdorff, or fractal, dimension of the set of solutions.

For example, the [Lorenz Attractor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorenz_attractor), which is a standard example in the theory of dynamical systems, apparently has a "correlation dimension" of 2.05, whatever that means.  [According to the authors](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/cgi-bin/nph-bib_query?bibcode=1983PhyD....9..189G&db_key=PHY) who derived this result, the correlation dimension "is closely related to the fractal dimension and the information dimension, but its computation is considerably easier."

What I really want is the following: does anyone know of a system of coupled differential equations, preferably with smooth coefficients, for which a non-integer Hausdorff dimension of the solution set can be derived in an elegant way?

Thanks!